# Magento tierprice calculation

Tags: magento-1.8, product, checkout, price

I created a couple of tierprices on our products but this is not calculating the way it should calculate.

For example when someone wants to buy 70 pieces of a patchcable it will cost €8,00928 per piece (rounded €8,01)

Now the total price of these products are €560,65 while we want it to be €560,70
The system is calculating 70 * €8,00928 = €560,65 while I want it to calculate 70 * €8,01 = €560,70

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the price per item for the tier to 8,01 (instead of 8,00928).

For more information see: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

Comment: no, the price is €12,56 per piece.
The tier we are using is 30,20%
it is not a fixed discount, but a percentage.

Comment: I assume the price for 1 patchcable is 12.56? And you've set up a tier price eg. qty = 50 and above / price = 8.00928? In that case the price per item in the tier price should be 8.01.
If this is not the case, you should add more information on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the tier pricing is automatically multiplying the total tier price calculation with 4 digits behind the decimal.
I entered our database and changed the following information in catalog_product_entity_tier_price

change: qty decimal 12,4 1.0000 
to
qty decimal 12,2 1.00

and

value decimal 12,4 0.0000
to
value decimal 12,2 0.00

This will fix the calculation